# SQL ODBC Drivers is FAILING for Access in Windows 7

Tags: odbc

using:  c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

The PC is running Windows 7 64bit

I am trying to use ODBC Driver to connect data to SQL Server (back-end data) for MS Access (front-end GUI), using the ODBC wizard but it keeps failing. I just had the Window 7 installed.

Comment: You'll probably need to add some details if you want some help...

Comment: I am trying to use ODBC Driver to connect data to SQL Server (back-end data) for MS Access (front-end GUI), using the ODBC wizard but it keeps failing.  I just had the Window 7 installed.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

That installs the drivers for OLEDB and ODBC. It needs to just set up the NEW connection string to the path of the .mdb file.